# Несколько критериев для одного поля

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть бд с сообщениями, которая содержит id отправителя, id получателя и само сообщение. Нужно сделать так чтобы выводились все сообщения от пользователя c id=1 к пользователю с id=2 и наоборот. Т.е. своего рода диалог. Пока запрос выглядит так `"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE fromMessage='1' and toMassage='2'"`, но нужно что-то типа `"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE fromMessage='1,2' and toMassage='1,2'"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE (fromMessage, toMessage) IN ((1, 2), (2, 1))
```

либо

```
WHERE LEAST(fromMessage, toMessage) = 1 
  AND GREATEST(fromMessage, toMessage) = 2
```

ну и ещё куча аналогичных вариантов

Но самый быстрый вариант - это UNION ALL.

Comment: Все понял, благодарю!